# Automatic spline fitting software

Tags: vector, line-art

Is there a (free) software for fitting splines to line graphics?

For example, I would like to sketch something on my android tablet or scan sketch and then place some nodes at the shape, and afterward, the vector graphic program should fit the spline to the lines.
This can't be too hard to implement, but I didn't find programs with such a feature.

I am *not* looking for vectorization like `potrace` (and the corresponding Inkscape binding) does it, as it results in hard to work with shapes. I am looking for a program, which fits splines to drawn paths. I have no problem placing a few landmark points before the spline is fitted to the drawn path.

---

### Example:

**Input image:**

[image: A bitmap with a line drawing]

**My preparation:**

[image: The bitmap with a polygon drawn over it]

**The result with manual fitting:**

[image: The polygon deformed to a curve that better approximates the shape]

**My question is about automating the last step.**

It's not dumb smoothing, but finding the spline which fits to the curve in the bitmap image and to just that curve (among others) that I pointed by clicking a poly-line.

Comment: Are you referring to **auto-tracing**? There are many apps capable of that.

Comment: @Scott I am not meaning vectorization like potrace (and the corresponding inkscape binding) does it, as it results in hard to work with shapes. I am explicitely looking for a program, which fits splines to drawn paths.

Comment: Spline fitting isnt hard at all (after all splines are designed for fitting). In fact most vector and cad software do it, to a different degree. Most have a freform draw tool that gets fitted, still does not seem any more workable than what you reject. But the question is rather how do you want to inoput and fit.

Comment: @user287001 I drew a few images in Inkscape by importing the bitmap and then creating a poly-line along the outline in the bitmap. Then I converted it to a curve and fitted the spline by hand. I then thought it couldn't be too hard to automate this. What I would like would be for example an Inkscape plugin, which snaps the segments to the drawn curves. I guess some expensive Adobe program has this, but are there free alternatives with this feature?

Comment: Fitting a vector path to match raster object with as few nodes as possible usually involves using the Pen/Bézier tool in graphics software - and this is a manual process, not automatic.  In vector software, other than auto tracing, the software can't see raster graphics at all. It doesn't know anything about raster graphics. Inkscape has a B-spline path effect as already mentioned, but it won't fit anything to a raster image automatically.

Comment: @BillyKerr its not true you know, theres quite a lot of leeway between autotrace and manual trace. I mean what op is looking for sounds more like curbe simplification, but with constraints. (yeah curve simplification is spline fitting)

Comment: @user287001 a bezier curve is in the family of splines. So a bezier is a spline.

Comment: @joojaa Hmmm, that's not how I read the question. To me it seems the OP wants to have curves/splines fit (or snap?) automatically to lines in a raster image.  Perhaps the wording is too vague, and an image showing what is wanted might be helpful at this stage.

Comment: Fit is bascially that @BillyKerr but im just looking at it from tools you have. SO bascially you can snap to autotrace. THis si after all snapping to a picture. And then you can jsut5 make point son that trace and fit a cure trough that. Which is the same as adding points that must be there to a simplify object. Same thing darta shufled aaround a bit.

Comment: @joojaa - Depending on what the OP actually wants, there's a possibility that  tools such as Illustrator's Curvature tool, or Inkscape's Spiro path effect might work.

Comment: @user287001 - yeah, actually that may be the actual source of the problem here, i.e. just an inability to use the Pen/Bézier tool effectively. I've seen lots of crap tutorials on the web showing people clicking straight lines all around a shape, then trying to adjust the bézier curves afterwards to fit them to  the shape. It's generally a waste of time. Much better to learn how to use the tool properly to create curves by clicking and dragging, and where to place nodes efficiently.

Comment: @user287001 yes au naturalment but how do you know op wants do draw a b-spline either i mean i could choose a catmul-rom spline or any of the other spline. I was more against your use of words than op's. Anyway if one draws a polyline and simplifies then it makes a fit trough the points...

Comment: I added an example and hope this makes clearer what I am looking for. I want to fit the spline to a bitmap, e.g., by using some form of edge detection. I am willing to prepare a poly-line to allow for better fitting, but would like an automatic optimization to minimize the difference between the spline and the edges in the bitmap.

Comment: I guess there's overlapping other curves. Otherwise you would use Inkscape's Centerline Autotrace (appeared in v1.0) which finds at least your example curve perfectly but would go astray if there were crossings. Right?

Comment: Nothing in the world would give the result that you propose. Because you in fact have sharp corners in places where there clearly are none. But yeah something like this could be done. Just smooth then copy the tangent info from the nearesest curve on a autotrace. Anyway it seems to me that your not really adressing your real problem but instead try to present us with a XY problem still.

Comment: @joojaa Having a better approximation is one of the reasons why I am asking the question. But the best approximation is not round everywhere, when the shape is not round. I am still after fitting a curve to a bitmap, if possible integrated in some free vector graphic program. The different types of tracing using potrace in inkscape always resulted in shapes which are more complicated to change later on than a manually fitted spline. But the problem of fitting such a spline should be solvable by a rather simple optimization, so I wonder why it's hard to find such tools.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting the image. It makes everything much clearer now.

The way you are proposing to do this won't work. Neither Inkscape nor any vector graphics software that I know of has any way of detecting edges in raster images, other than with auto tracing. So, a different approach is required.

Use the Centreline option in Inkscape's *Path > Trace Bitmap* function.

It does exactly what you want, fully automatically, without the need to even draw the lines yourself. Obviously centreline tracing is not so useful for more complex designs, but for the example you posted, it's almost perfect.

**Example**: Original raster image is on left, resulting centreline trace in the middle, and the Trace bitmap options on the right.

[image]
Click on image above to see larger

The only thing you may need to do manually is to increase the stroke width in the Fill and Stroke Panel (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) to match the raster image.

Inkscape also has a Simplify command if you think the trace has created too many nodes. Also if you want sharper corners you could select specific nodes and turn them into corner nodes, and make small adjustments to their positioning.

Another more manual approach in cases where Centreline tracing might fail is to use the Bézier Tool(aka Pen Tool) in Inkscape, and click and drag Bézier curves as you go. It will save time rather than trying to fit/adjust curves afterwards. Another possibility if you are not familiar with creating your own Bézier curves in this way is to use the Spiro option in the tool controls along the top to automate the curves. When using the latter option, holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while you click will add a corner node, while regular mouse clicks produce curve nodes.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I still hope if there may be tools (it's a well-known optimization problem in science). I am not sure if my use-case (vectorizing anime style sketches) will work that easy. My previous tries with the vectorization tool did not work out very well. But I'll check what I can achieve using the method in your post.

Comment: @allo this only works for rather simple shapes. For anything more complex, you'll need to learn how to use the Bézier tool properly. Clicking lines, then adjusting the curves later is not efficient.

Comment: @allo its not normal for scientists to do a piecevise fitting like you did but rather smooth fitting the problem is not at all that i can not fit. but rather whet heurestics would you use to determine the cusp and where to seatch the data from. So the problem is really 3 of the 2 bottommost points. Why on eart would any fitting algorithm fit them like that, what kind of function would minimize that way.

Comment: @joojaa You are probably thinking about general curve fitting. That's another thing, but not useful for vector graphics. I am talking about optimization of splines (or other piecewise curves), which is a problem from the computer graphics part of computer science. Discussion related papers would be a topic for the compsci site. It is not too useful to discuss them here, as I don't want to implement it myself but am looking if there are some solutions which implemented such algorithms in a user-friendly way.

Comment: @allo no im aware of this subject, i have optimizers like this in cartography and engineering software. But why would the optimizer make a cusp in the southwest most point of the curve. The data ios smooth enough to begin with what would prompt thw algorthm to make it that way?

Comment: I now tried your approach. It seems to fail as soon as you have a more complicated line art. That's why I think it is preferrable to create a rough draft and then fit the spline as any method that tries to fit the whole image needs to handle a lot of ambiguous cases and will fail for many images. Your method for example fails with an anime character and either creates a complicated and wrong zig-zag path or many not connected segments depending on the pre-processing (like improving contrast) of the image.

Comment: @joojaa My sketch in the post is far from perfect. An optimizer would probably not create the cusp there. But you may need cusps for some images. Think, for example, of a heart shape.

Comment: @allo - yes that's what I said already. Centreline tracing only works for simple shapes. The only viable alternative for complex vector work is to create the vectors manually, by using the available tools. Trying to fit curves after you've drawn the lines is a waste of time. Learn how to use the Bézier tool properly.